# Use cake to perform git commit without name and email

Tags: git, cakebuild

The cake [GitCommit](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Git/GitAliases/B2287677) alias wants a name and email:

```cs
public static GitCommit GitCommit(this ICakeContext context, DirectoryPath repositoryDirectoryPath, string name, string email, string message)
```

How can I commit without specifying them (and it would use the repo's defaults)?

For example, the same as I can do in the shell: `$ git commit -m message`.

Comment: "repo's defaults", what exactly do you mean here? If you do `git commit -m message`, you have those values defined locally, these are either configured globally or in your local repository, but even if they're defined in your local repository, those values are not propagated to remote repositories. So github and such have no such "default".

Comment: You can apply settings for just one call with `-c` IIRC. Call `git help -c` will list the settings to override, like `author.email` and `author.name`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks that is true. Though not everything ends up on github. I was hoping there was a way to make it read the repo's config for the default values.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks. I could do that in the shell, but sadly `cake` has no such option (that I've found, so far).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reasonable workaround:

```cs
var name  = GitConfigGet<string>(repoDirectory, "user.name"));
var email = GitConfigGet<string>(repoDirectory, "user.email");

GitCommit(repoDirectory, name, email, "message");
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "remote repository" when making commits: you're making a commit *in* **your** repository, which is by definition local. (If you're using a web interface, the web interface is making a commit in *its* repository, which is local to it.)

Answer (score 1):

The git cli does a lot a of things other clients might or might not do.

*Cake.Git* uses [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) to provide access to git. [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp), in turn, uses [libgit2](https://libgit2.org).

[libgit2](https://libgit2.org) requires a username and email to be explicitly specified when adding a commit and so does *Cake.Git*.

You can, as you wrote in your answer, check the config for existing values, but I would strongly suggest checking them not to be empty, before using them.